# How long does it take to learn Thaumaturgy/Necromancy rituals?

Tags: magic, world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, vampire-the-dark-ages

I found in Rites of the Blood on pg.136 that rituals can be learned for free for Tremere/Giovanni/Other as long a teacher is available + other resources (those are not a problem) but it takes time. I wasn't able to find how much time. That information might have been published in another companion book.

Could you point me in the right direction to figure out how long it takes to learn a ritual based on it's level?

Would prefer information published in recent editions if available such as Vampire the Masquerade V20 or Vampire the Dark Ages 20. Not just the core books; any Vampire V20 books would do, like Rites of the Blood.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your answer can be found in the V20 core rulebook on page 230:

> Learning a new ritual can take anywhere from a few nights (Level One ritual) to months or years (Level Five ritual). Some mystics have studied individual rituals for decades, or even centuries.

On the assumption that the final sentence is Storyteller puffery, you can presume that the number of nights is proportional to the dots of the ritual, and that whereas you might pick up a •• or ••• Ritual in a few sessions, a ••••• Ritual might take an entire Chronicle to learn.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is in "Blood Sacrifice - The Thaumaturgy Companion", page 14, in "Learning Times".

Ritual Level - Estimated Learning Time

- One - One Week
- Two - One Month
- Three - One Season (Three Months)
- Four - Two Seasons
- Five - One Year
- Six+ - Storyteller's Discretion

I'd expect to help ;)

Comment: Note that this book is for the Revised Edition of the game, which predated V20 by about a decade, and doesn't cover thaumaturgical rituals (despite being a "thaumaturgy companion").
https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Blood_Sacrifice:_The_Thaumaturgy_Companion

Answer (score 1):

Pg. 272 5th edition corebook: "Expect a Ritual to take at least the square of its rating in weeks to learn."

I.e. a level 1 ritual would take 1x1 = 1 week to learn, whereas a level 5 ritual would take 5x5 = 25 weeks to learn.

Comment: Although that answer is true for [tag:vampire-the-masquerade-5e], it doesn't seem to be true for earlier editions.

Answer (score 1):

You needed only to turn to the next page! :)

Page 137 of *Rites of the Blood* has alternate rules for learning thaumaturgical rituals on that allow the character to roll to determine how much time they must spend studying, with more adept thaumaturges having larger dice pools and a higher likelihood of learning more quickly.

> Mastering a ritual requires **an extended Intelligence +
> Occult roll** with a difficulty equal to the ritual level + 3. The total number of successes needed is equal to
> the ritual level × 5. **Each roll represents a week** spent
> analyzing, memorizing, and experimenting with the ritual,
> although the character is free to do other things during
> the same period if he can devote at least a few hours every
> night to study. If the player dedicates his character’s full
> attention to learning the ritual and doing nothing else
> except feeding, **each roll may represent a single night**.

However, if the ritual is from an unfamiliar school of blood magic,

> **The total number of successes** needed to
> adapt and master a foreign ritual **increases to ritual level × 10**. However, the player may subtract the character’s total
> number of dots assigned to all of her blood magic paths
> from the number of required successes, to a minimum
> of half the normal number of successes. This reduction
> represents the extent to which greater fluency with one’s
> own school makes it easier to adapt foreign rituals to it.