# How many rituals should a Blood Sorcerer of a given age know?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

A newly created Blood Sorcerer somehow gets knowledge of one level 1 ritual. To learn new rituals, he doesn't need XP, only time and a willing teacher/other knowledge source.

But how many rituals should an experienced one know? I didn't manage to find any mention of this number in V20 core book and don't think that basing this on [ritual learning time](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/84324/30214) is a good thing, as Kindred (let alone the ghouls!) don't spend their entire (un)life learning rituals, they just have other things to do.

I am using V20 edition, but answer from any edition will work just fine. Probably even some adaptation from nWoD if cWoD doesn't cover it and nWoD does, or a house rule that you have tested.

Comment: Despite saying “because I suspect that it might have a bit different rules”, I'm unclear on why the [vampire-dark-ages] tag is on the question. Are you playing V:DA and need an answer for it?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I play both of them, and as I suspec Dark Ages to have different rules, I want an answer about both V:DA and VtM.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy In order to avoid getting answers that only address one of the two editions, it might be best to ask the same question for different editions.  As it is, any answer that only addresses one of the two editions on *this* question will be *de facto* bad answers because they don't address the full scope of the question.

Comment: @LegendaryDude Edited answer to mark that I will accept an answer from any edition, and even a house rule. Is it ok? Also it feels like [vampire-dark-ages] tag is going to fade now.

Comment: I guess my question would be, "To what end?" Is this a PC you're making, an NPC to challenge players? Character sheet ornamentation?

Comment: @Jadasc I am interested in all of what you have written. I just have totally no idea of what I have asked about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm running a game that blends VtM V20 and 2ed. In that game I have a few considerations:

For player characters I think that it should mostly be dictated by roleplaying experience more than age. If they want new rituals, it becomes a matter of finding the resources and then enough game time passing. We usually treat this sort of thing as an extended roll. For my group, this exact scenario hasn't come up because we don't have any serious magic users.

For NPCs I have two tracks. For NPCs in the city's "milieu" (which means they exist for the players to interact with but aren't major agents in the plot without player intervention) I mostly build the character according to the standard character creation rules and then give one ritual per dot in any magical path (not discipline) of equal or lesser level than the character's overall corresponding Discipline rating.

For major NPCs (those that drive the plot with or without player intervention) it's pure storyteller need. The rituals themselves are really not balanced well within or between sorcerous Disciplines, so I don't like limiting such important characters while creating them-- the builds end up too fragile to deal with players taking the story off the rails, and useless rituals are a waste. I do try to stick to the one-ritual-per-magic-path-dot, as with milieu characters, but I don't assign all of the specific rituals right away.

I'll give major characters rituals that the character "would know", in the sense that if the character regularly does something a ritual supports or makes possible, then the character knows it and this "uses up" one of the allotted rituals. The rest are fluid until they are needed. This flexibility remains until the chapter in which the players first meet the character ends (more or less), and then the rest of the fluid rituals are assigned to ones I think fit their concepts and backstories or they are lost. For high-level rituals I might require the NPC to devote resources to discovering/learning them "off camera", but that ties in with some other house systems I use.

**TL;DR: The rituals an NPC knows (and their number) should support the needs of the story first and foremost regardless of any guideline. After that I aim roughly for one ritual per path dot, loosely adjusted for the NPC's access to ritual knowledge, inclination to study,  and relevant Attributes, Abilities (primarily Intelligence and Occult, but others sometimes apply), and Disciplines.**

Comment: Can you please clarify your question a bit? How many rituals of each level would a thaumaturge with Lure of Flames 4 and Path of Blood 3 have by your rules? 7?

Comment: Yes, in your example I would aim to give the character 7 rituals. The ritual levels available build as Thaumaturgy dots are gained and so the character ***could*** have seven level 1 rituals, or six level 2 rituals, or 5 level 3, or 4 at level 4. The "extra" rituals (so the total known is 7) can be made up with any combinations of lower-level rituals. The specific choices of ritual are whatever suits the story/character best, and even the 7 ritual total isn't set in stone. But that is the rough guideline I've been using.

Comment: OK. I will wait a bit to give others a chance to answer, and then I will most likely accept your answer.